# View access table in front end after removing lookups in back end

Tags: ms-access, lookup-tables

I have removed the lookup information from a back-end Access table.

When I open the front-end mdb and try to view the raw data in the table, I am presented with an 'Enter Parameter Values' dialog box, and Access is indicating that it wants a value for 'Lookup_[ForeignKeyColumn].Desc'.

I can view the design of the table in the front end, and on the lookup tab, all the fields are set to 'Text Box', so it doesn't look like any references are floating around.

Queries are still fine - I can access the data - just looking at the table on its own is the difficulty.

Has anyone seen this before and knows what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:  [Refresh Linked Tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/view-refresh-or-change-the-file-name-and-path-for-linked-tables-mdb-HP005187623.aspx)

From the front end, I had to go into Tools -> Database Utilities -> Linked Table Manager

and nominate to update all files.

Answer (score 1):

Access has a lot of "ghost" issues.  I've been working with it for 20 years, and I can't tell you how many times I've had to rebuild databases because mystery queries were running in the background, or forms continued to require data entry, even though the controls had been deleted.

Try creating a new, fresh database with nothing in it.  Then, import all of the forms, queries, modules and macros into it.  See if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, however for me refreshing the linked tables did not work, neither did relinking the tables after first breaking the links.

In my case the field "Order By" in the property sheet of the front end table was filled. Clearing this resolved the issue.